# Limited access to different roles in Django

Tags: python, django, user-roles, django-permissions

I'm building a Django web application in which I have two roles e.g. `sys_user` and an `exhibitor`. When a `sys_user` logins in he has access to all the urls and app modules but an `exhibitor` will have limited access i.e he will have access to specific urls and app modules. Consider the following:

When a `sys_user` logs in he should see (the following sidebar) and have access to all the modules like:

```
--- Module1
--- Module2
--- Module3
--- Module4
```

When an `exhibitor` logs he should see (the following sidebar) and have access to only the following modules like:

```
--- Module1
--- Module2
```

Now I know that Django provides its own permissions but I don't really know how they fit into my situation or is there any other alternative approach for this. Please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Where should this access be placed on? on Templates level, view?

Comment: Any where would work as long as the exhibitor cannot directly access the restricted modules directly from the urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this on Template level permissions are stored in `{{ perm }}` variable.

From Django docs:

```
{% if perms.foo %}
    <p>You have permission to do something in the foo app.</p>
    {% if perms.foo.can_vote %}
        <p>You can vote!</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if perms.foo.can_drive %}
        <p>You can drive!</p>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <p>You don't have permission to do anything in the foo app.</p>
{% endif %}
```

More information could be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permissions).

Also it is possible to do on url level:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$', login_required(direct_to_template), {'template': 'foo_index.html'}),
    )
```

In this example `login_required` decorator is used. But you can create you own decorator, where you will check user in request object and based on it , make decision what to do(redirect, forbidden page etc.)

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/decorators/) are comprehensive example of decorators usage in Django.

Simple example of custom decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test

@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.user_name != 'sys_user', login_url='/myapp/denied/')
def some_view(request):
```

Comment: What permissions should I add and where (in views.py) for my specific case?

Comment: @Sibtain You can grant sys_user with admin rights and check in view if request.user.is_superuser  and do some stuff specific for admin user.

Comment: Ok. If I use the template level approach does it also avoid the direct url navigation to restricted urls?

Comment: @Sibtain - like url's to --- Module1 for example? I think for direct url you will need add also decorator on urls.

Comment: the login_required decorator or a custom decorator?

Comment: @Sibtain - added custom decorator example for you in my answer. You can use smth like that to protect some url's and make them accessible only for sys_user, for example.

Comment: I eventually used a combination of both template level access and user_passes_test decorator. Thanks